# Angular Custom Validation with Parameter

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous

I have created a custom validator that takes one parameter (an array of strings) using a factory function which I then export to my component:

location.validator.ts

```
export function locationsValidator(arr: string[]): ValidatorFn {

return (control: AbstractControl): {[key:string]: any} | null => {

    const forbidden = arr.includes(control.value);
    return forbidden ? { 'invalidLocation': {value: control.value}} : null;
  }

}
```

The validator works fine with a hard-coded array of locations. However, the locations in the component are not hard-coded - they are pulled from the back-end on init - and Angular does not update the validator when the array of locations has been assigned.

I tried to assign the validator to the control once the locations have arrived using setValidators but it states that the form is undefined when I do so.

Is my only option to do a separate async call using an async validator???

**UPDATE:** Adding the following code to the end of onInit works [but this is a hack!!]:

```
setTimeout( () => this.specsForm.get('loc').setValidators([Validators.required, locationsValidator(this.municipalities)]),1000)
```

To repeat, if I were to take the above code out of setTimeout (at the bottom of ngOnit) and put it into the back-end service call at the top of ngOnit it would not recognise the get() function because specsForm is undefined.

Below is the specsForm which resides in the constructor:

```
this.specsForm = formBuilder.group({
    loc: [[''], []],
    types: this.formBuilder.group({
        piso: [false],
        casa: [false],
        parking: [false],
        suelo: [false],
        local: [false],
        trastero: [false],
        oficina: [false]
      }),
    price: [[0,500000]],
    sqm: [[0,200]],
    bedsMin: [1],
    bathMin: [1],
    lift: [false],
    parking: [false],
    new: [false],
  })
```

Comment: can you also share the form used in this use case? seeing validation method is cool, but to help you one needs to know full context.